# Most efficient query to grab minimum value of a column depending on it's mapping value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's an example

```
carsOwned
name|car
1   |acura
1   |honda
1   |mercedes
2   |honda
2   |mercedes
3   |acura
4   |mercedes
```

```
carValue
car     | value
honda   | 1
acura   | 2
mercedes| 3
```

```
Output
name | min
1    |honda
2    |honda
3    |acura
4    |mercedes
```

In the output, each name displays the cheapest car (values shown in table carValue) they own.
Unsure of how to do this operation in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: can't say I understand what you are asking... why isn't Mercedes 1?  it is 1 in the first table?  maybe you should explain your tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that, for each `name` in `carOwned`, you want to select the car that has the lowest value in `carValue`.

This could be adressed by joining both tables and adding a `NOT EXISTS` condition to ensure that only the record with the smallest possible value is retained:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM carsOwned o
INNER JOIN carValue v ON v.car = o.car
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM carsOwned o1
    INNER JOIN carValue v1 ON v1.car = o1.car
    WHERE o1.name = o.name AND v1.value < v.value
);
```

Or in MySQL 8.0, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT name, car
FROM (
    SELECT o.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.name ORDER BY v.value) rn
    FROM carsOwned o
    INNER JOIN carValue v ON v.car = o.car
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jnMk4pvRDefAtAFJZ7AVFx/1)**:

```
| name | car      |
| ---- | -------- |
| 1    | honda    |
| 2    | honda    |
| 3    | acura    |
| 4    | mercedes |
```